# Как сделать копию спана?

Tags: javascript, html, css

разметка такая

```html
 <button class="btn btn--info">
    <span>кнопка</span>
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn--info">
    <span>другое название кнопки</span>
    </button>
```

после загрузки страницы получить такое

```html
 <button class="btn btn--info">
    <span>кнопка</span>
    
    <span class="no-active>кнопка</span>
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn--info">
    <span>другое название кнопки</span>
    <span class="no-active>другое название кнопки</span>
    </button>
```

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  right: 15px;
  top: calc(50% - 6px);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn--info">
<span>кнопка</span>
</button>

<button class="btn btn--info">
<span>другое название кнопки</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn--info').forEach(btn => {
  let cSpan = btn.querySelector('span').cloneNode(true);
  cSpan.classList.add('no-active');
  btn.appendChild(cSpan);
});
```

```css
.no-active {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
 <button class="btn btn--info">
   <span>кнопка</span>
 </button>

 <button class="btn btn--info">
   <span>другое название кнопки</span>
 </button>
```